# How can I redirect to error page when wrong url is entered?

Tags: reactjs

How can I redirect to 'Notfound' page when wrong url is entered.

I have following Routes:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="**" component={Notfound} />
</Switch>
```

I have tried "**" as path but this did not worked.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: i think this is a duplicate question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181678/404-page-in-react

Answer (score 2):

A `<Route>` with no path always matches. So you can try something like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
  <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />

  <Route component={Notfound}/>
</Switch>
```